# Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from /192.168.2.13:46500 is closed

Tags: apache-spark

I create two temporaryview from df: one from mongo, another from hive.
Then I join this two tables on single key, finally insert into hive.

The result indeed successfully inserted into hive, but there are some exceptions in the log:

> 19/08/21 16:30:35 ERROR client.TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1
>   requests outstanding when connection from /192.168.2.13:46508 is
>   closed
>
> 19/08/21 16:30:35 ERROR client.TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1
>   requests outstanding when connection from /192.168.2.13:46498 is
>   closed 19/08/21 16:30:35 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed
>   broadcast_8_piece0 on s2:44369 in memory (size: 650.0 KB, free: 5.2
>   GB)
>
> 19/08/21 16:30:35 WARN storage.BlockManagerMaster: Failed to remove
>   broadcast 8 with removeFromMaster = true - Connection from
>   /192.168.2.13:46508 closed java.io.IOException: Connection from
>   /192.168.2.13:46508 closed

Comment: This can happen in distributed environment. Some task can fail and driver will launch another task. If you check Spark UI you can see failed attempts. If failure reaches to the threshold limit lie 3 times then job will fail.

Comment: @Prateek Prateek then how to fix it

Answer (score 3):

In my case i fixed this by increasing to 50000s (random big number from my head) timeout  "spark.network.timeout" in configuration.